# Create Tar On Ubuntu And Mac With Same MD5

Tags: 18.04, mac, rsync, tar, checksums

I have a folder of files which I am trying to tar into an archive. I have the same files on a Mac and on a Ubuntu machine. If I run an rsync it shows that the directories are the same, but if I tar them and then take a MD5 sum the results are different. I have tried with both GNU tar and BSD tar on the Mac. Is there some option that has to be used to make the result come out the same?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The same thing happens on Ubuntu to RHEL 7 as well. Here are the steps I am taking:

- Create tar archive of directory on Ubuntu, using --exclude='.*' to exclude hidden files
- take sha256sum of tar file
- use gpg to encrypt archive
- take sha256sum of encrypted tar file
- transfer file to Mac/RHEL 7 machine
- check sha256sum of encrypted file on Mac/RHEL 7
- decrypt and check sha256sum of tar file
- untar archive
- tar files again on Mac/RHEL 7
- take sha256sum of new archive

This sum will be different from the original tar file, even though the files in the archive are the same. I've used tar -t and rsync to check this. I've tried using --owner=0 --group=0 --mtime='1970-01-01' --mode=664 on both ends as well but this doesn't help.

I'm assuming that something like the tar version or something is added a file header and that this is different on each machine because of the different OS versions. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Check if  there's hidden files in the folders, and perhaps encodings of text files.

Comment: I guess a lot of different things are important to note here, version of `tar` and libraries are only some of them ...

Comment: Mac has some hidden files usually. for example `.DS_Store`. That might be the reason.

Comment: I'm using exclude so no hidden files are added to the archive, and I've double checked this afterward with 'tar -t'